# How to prevent conflicting events?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

so I am creating a stove/hob control panel. Using checkboxes there is a main power in order to turn on each hob, you then can select each of the hobs to ignite the flame once the main power is on and you can adjust the intensity of burn with a scale of 0-9 (label called Topleft_Burn in the example) on each hob. When you turn on/off each individual hob, the burn scale appears and disappears by the code below;

```
    private void Hob_Topleft_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Hob_Topleft.Checked)
        {
            Pan2.Visible = true;
            Topleft_burn.Visible = true;
            Feeback.AppendText("Top Left Hob: ON" + "\r\n");
        }
        else
        {
            Pan2.Visible = false;
            Topleft_burn.Visible = false;
            Feeback.AppendText("Top Left Hob: OFF" + "\r\n");
        }
```

However, I am trying to have all the hob powers set to unchecked and become invisible when the main hob power is turned off (Unchecked) All these items are within its own panel and I have tried this code below however this does not reset everything to its default.

```
    private void Hob_Power_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Hob_Power.Checked)
        {
            Hob_Bottomleft.Enabled = true;
            Hob_Topleft.Enabled = true;
            Hob_Bottomright.Enabled = true;
            Hob_Topright.Enabled =true;
            Feeback.AppendText("Hob Power: ON" + "\r\n");
        }
        else
        {
            Hob_Bottomleft.Enabled = false;
            Hob_Topleft.Enabled = false;
            Hob_Bottomright.Enabled = false;
            Hob_Topright.Enabled = false;
            Feeback.AppendText("Hob Power: OFF" + "\r\n");
        }
```

I'm not a very experienced coder so is there a simple way of sorting this? I thought giving some context would help explain what I am trying to do. Hope this all makes sense.

Comment: Hi. It is really nicely explained. Could you post `.aspx` part containing checkboxes and other relevant data, just so we can be sure what is going on and find the solution easier?

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. Sorry I'm not sure what the .aspx part is and how to find it, still pretty new to visual studio.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the code? You said *"this does not reset everything to its default"*, but it's not clear to me what the difference is between the behavior you're expecting and the actual behavior of the code.

Comment: `.aspx` is a webpage and it will help to post here HTML from that webpage.

Comment: So for example in real life, if you turned off a device by its socket switch, everything loses power and you cannot use any button until the mains power is switched back on and any sub systems that originally set to on would be back to a default of off even after the whole system is rebooted. So when I press the mains power button to off everything disappears however when turned back on, my sub systems still are in the state they were left in. Does this make sense?

Comment: Sorry Marko , I've been trying to find out how to do this but cant seem to figure it out. Does it matter that this is a windows form application?

Comment: So i figured out the issue, I was using the .enabled but I also needed to be using the .Checked and set them to false in order for the checked state to remain to default until a click event on the individual hob power occurs again. However my increment labels do not reset, any ideas?

Comment: @RAG Ok, my bad, yes, that's the reason, it is a windows form application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> set to unchecked and become invisible

If you want to set all `hob powers` to be unchecked, you need to set their [CheckBox.Checked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checked?view=netcore-3.1) property  to `false`.

```
Hob_Bottomleft.Checked = false;
Hob_Topleft.Checked = false;
Hob_Bottomright.Checked = false;
Hob_Topright.Checked = false;
```